# ComboBox DisplayMember, ValueMember, and DataSource Method

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource, valuemember

I am working on a c# winforms program that has three comboboxes, each combobox has a different displaymember, valuemember, and datasource. I would like to try to create a method in which I can use to set the member values and datasource that works for all three comboboxes

here is what I am currently using for the comboboxes

```
private void kitLoad (string kitDisplay, string kitValue, object kitSource)
{
     kits_comboBox.DisplayMember = kitDisplay;
     kits_comboBox.ValueMember = kitValue;
     kits_comboBox.DataSource = kitSource;
}
private void pspLoad(string pspDisplay, string pspValue, object pspSource)
{
     psp_comboBox.DisplayMember = pspDisplay;
     psp_comboBox.ValueMember = pspValue;
     psp_comboBox.DataSource = pspSource;
}
private void plateLoad(string plateDisplay, string plateValue, object plateSource)
{
     plates_comboBox.DisplayMember = plateDisplay;
     plates_comboBox.ValueMember = plateValue;
     plates_comboBox.DataSource = plateSource;
}
```

It does work, But I feel like I could compress all of that into one method, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just pass your combo along

```cs
private void LoadCombo(ComboBox cbo, string disp, string val, object data)
{
     cbo.DisplayMember = disp;
     cbo.ValueMember = val;
     cbo.DataSource = data;
}
```

will work for any combo box

```
LoadCombo(kits_comboBox, "displayProperty", "valueProperty", data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked flawlessly. Much appreciated